# Доступ к созданному на телефоне файлу с ПК

Tags: java, android, excel

Создаю xls файл на java в android при помощи `apache poi`.
В менеджере файлов телефона он виден, если подключить к ПК через шнур файл не видно.
Если телефоном переместить этот файл куда-либо ПК его начинает видеть.
Вроде что-то с правами, но разобраться не могу.

Модуль:

```
public static boolean makeXls(String[][] data) throws IOException {
    Boolean result = true;

    Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("Contacts");

    // Нумерация начинается с нуля


    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        for(int j=0; j<data[i].length; j++){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
            cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Обрабатываем файл
    String newFname = file;
    Boolean existFile = true;
    int i = 1;
    //Генерируем новое имя файла если такой уже есть
    while (existFile) {
        if (new File(newFname + ".xls").exists()) {
            newFname = file + i;
        }
        else
            existFile = false;
        i += 1;
    };

    try {
        FileOutputStream resFile = new FileOutputStream(newFname + ".xls");

        book.write(resFile);
        resFile.flush();
        resFile.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
        result = false;
    }

    book.close();

    File curFile = new File(newFname + ".xls");

    curFile.getAbsoluteFile().setReadable(true);
    curFile.getAbsoluteFile().setWritable(true);

    System.err.println(curFile.canRead());
    System.err.println(curFile.canWrite());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.
Нужно было после создания файла сообщи файловой системе о его существовании.

Сделал так:
File curFile = new File(newFname + ".xls");

```
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx, new String[] {curFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```